# accessing of different classes through includes

Tags: php, class, include

I have a problem with the accessing of classes.

index.php

```
 include('includes/header.php');
 include('includes/step1.php');
 include('includes/footer.php');
```

header.php

```
session_start();

include('php/classes/Errorhandler.php');

include('php/classes/User.php');

$errorhandler = new Errorhandler();

$user = new User();

// Test
print_r($errorhandler->errors);

...html
```

Errorhandler.php

```
class Errorhandler {
   public $errors = array();
   ...
}
```

User.php

```
class User {
   public function __construct() {

   if($this->grab_computerid()) {
      if(!$this->grab_mandant()) {
         $errorhandler->errors[] = "102: There was an error.";
      }

      if(!$this->grab_os()) {
         $errorhandler->errors[] = "103: There was an error.";
      }
   } else {
      $errorhandler->errors[] = "101: There was an error.";
   }
}

private function grab_computerid() {
    $sqlconnection = new SqlConnection();

    $conn = $sqlconnection->db_connect();

    if ($conn) {
        $query = "SELECT Computer_Idn FROM " . DB_PC_TABLE . " WHERE DeviceName = ?";

        $params = array($this->get_hostname());

        if ($sqlconnection->query($query, $params)) {
            $computer_id = $sqlconnection->fetchRow();

            $this->set_computer_id($computer_id['Computer_Idn']);

            return true;
            echo "Test";
        } else {
            $errorhandler->errors[] = "Statement error occurred.";
        }
    } else {
        $errorhandler->errors[] = "Can't connect to database.";
        // test
        print_r($errorhandler->errors);
    }
    $sqlconnection->db_disconnect();
}
}
```

The index.php includes the relevant sections to build the site. In header.php I create two objects (1. errorhandler, 2. user). The User class check the return (boolean) from the sqlconnection. I know, that I use the wrong password and get a false. So the if ($conn) prints the print_r($errorhandler->errors) correctly. But when I want to show the errors in step1.php, the array errors is empty.

step1.php

```
// show negative messages
if ($errorhandler->errors) {
   foreach ($errorhandler->errors as $error) {
   echo '<div class="alert alert-danger message"><strong>Error: </strong>' . $error . '</div>';    
      }
   }
```

I tested it in header.php also and the errors array is empty too. So, the errors array is only filled in the User.php class, but I want to display the erros in step1.php. Is there a problem with the includes?

---

Edit:
Hope to make it clearer:

header.php

```
// load the class Errorhandler
require_once('php/classes/Errorhandler.php');

// load the class User
require_once('php/classes/User.php');

// create errorhandler object
$errorhandler = new Errorhandler();

// create user object
$user = new User();

print_r($errorhandler->errors);
```

I set an error in class User:

```
$errorhandler->errors[] = "Can't connect to database.";
```

The array $errorhandler->errors is empty in header.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call a function. You cannot get value directly.

1st->`$errorhandler = new Errorhandler();`

2nd->Errorhandler.php

```
class Errorhandler {
function error() //create a function like this
{
$error= /*any error*/;
return $error;
}
}
```

3rd->

```
if ($err=$errorhandler->error()) {
foreach ($err as $error) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger message"><strong>Error:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
  }
```

}

Also try using require_once() instead of include();

Answer (score 0):

Try using `require_once` instead of `include`.  `require_once` will throw an error when something goes wrong and kill the script.  These errors should appear in an error_log file in the same folder as the file which has the `include` in it.  `include` will only issue a warning and let the script continue.  I personally use `require_once` everywhere.  Also, double check your `include` paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass $errorhandler to User class.
Like this:

```
$user = new User($errorhandler);
```

And in User class:

```
class User {
    protected $err;
    public function __construct($errorhandler) {
        $this->err = $errorhandler;
        //rest of your code
    }

    //rest of your code
}
```

or simply add: global $errorhandler; inside User constructor.

Comment: I dont understand why the error array is empty. The array is public and I created an object of the class. After I include the step1.php and the error (which was filled in the User.php in the test print) is empty.

Comment: maybe it is a good way to make a getter and setter for the error array in Errorhandler class?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. I prefer you make adaptation in User class (like I gave in example)

Comment: Inside user constructor add:

    global $errorhandler;

But I would go with my answered solution anyway :)